# Websocket peerjs video conference

Tags: websocket, webrtc, ratchet, peerjs, video-conferencing

I am making a video conference using webrtc and/or peerjs and i am new to this.
I am using socketo.me as webrtc and the concept is it is like meet.google.com

I want to ask you guys something:

1. Do I need to use php websocket even though i am already using peerjs?
2. What is the flow of this project? Do i use websocket to restore the socketid and use it to the users and use peerjs to call the other user?
3. If you have a scratch can i see it?
4. This is the sample that i worked out and the problem is in the picture too: 
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/jftev.png

If I have wrong question please correct me and enlighten me on how to do this project thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience I would not recommend using **Peerjs**, it is incompatible in some cases with cross browsers and usually gives irreparable errors which means that it is not the best option.

If you want something like Google Meet I would recommend 2 options:

1- https://github.com/livekit/livekit-server

2- https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection (This second one is more basic to use)

Of the two options, the better one is **LiveKit**, scalable, without errors between browsers, several SDK clients and examples in: **Android**, **ReactNative**, **Flutter**, **Javascript**, **Etc**.

I hope I've helped.

Comment: Can i use those in my project brother? I am using php and javascript

Comment: Of course, in fact you can create the room with Php and control who can or cannot enter, it also has Webhook to control the events of the room for example: if someone enters or leaves, it has a Javascript SDK: `https://github.com /livekit/client-sdk-js`.

Comment: I also share the PHP SDK with you ;) `https://github.com/agence104/livekit-server-sdk-php` (To control the rooms, create them, give access, etc)